# Why $w_i=\pi/n$ Chebyshev–Gauss quadrature?

Tags: special-functions, chebyshev-polynomials, quadrature

In [Chebyshev–Gauss quadrature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev%E2%80%93Gauss_quadrature#cite_note-AS1-1) we have
$$\int _{-1}^{+1}{\frac {f(x)}{\sqrt {1-x^{2}}}}\,dx\approx \sum _{i=1}^{n}w_{i}f(x_{i})$$
where
$$x_{i}=\cos \left({\frac {2i-1}{2n}}\pi \right)$$
and the weight $w_i=\pi/n$. Why $w_i=\pi/n$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we change variables by $x=\cos\theta$, then the integral  can be evaluated by dividing the interval into $n$ parts, using the midpoint rule on a circle, $$\int_{-1}^1\frac{f(x)}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}dx=\int_0^\pi f(\cos\theta)\,d\theta\approx\sum_{i=1}^nf(x_i)\frac{\pi}{n}$$ where the $x_i=\cos\theta_i$ are as written in the question.

---

For a fuller explanation of the weights:

The Cheybshev polynomials $T_n$ are orthogonal, that is $\int_{-1}^1\frac{T_i(x)T_j(x)}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}dx=\int_0^\pi \cos(i\theta)\cos(j\theta)\,d\theta=0$ for $i\ne j$.

To approximate the integral by $\sum_iw_if(x_i)$, we may require that the integral is exact on the $T_j$, $j=0,\ldots,n-1$, that is $$\sum_{i=1}^nw_iT_j(x_i)=\int_{-1}^1\frac{T_j(x)}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}dx$$
This is essentially the matrix equation $$\begin{pmatrix}1&\cdots&1\\ \cos\theta_1&\cdots&\cos\theta_n\\\cos2\theta_1&\cdots&\cos2\theta_n\\\vdots\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}w_1\\\vdots \\w_n\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}\pi\\0\\\vdots\\0\end{pmatrix}$$

One can invert this matrix, or else notice that $$\begin{pmatrix}1&\cdots&1\\ \cos\theta_1&\cdots&\cos\theta_n\\\cos2\theta_1&\cdots&\cos2\theta_n\\\vdots\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}1\\\vdots\\1\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}n\\0\\\vdots\\0\end{pmatrix}$$ to conclude that $w_i=\pi/n$.

Comment: That doesn't explain why the weights in the sense of Gaussian quadrature should be uniform. Certainly if they are uniform then they are $\frac{\pi}{n}$, though.

Comment: @Ian Thanks. Does this explain better?

Comment: It seems mysterious to me that the weights would be determined solely by exactness on $T_j$ for $j=0,1,\dots,n-1$, when the degree of exactness in fact goes up to $2n-1$. But otherwise this makes sense.

Comment: @Ian Yes that's the amazing thing about Gaussian quadrature. It works to degree $2n-1$ for *any* orthonormal basis, not just the Chebyshev.

Comment: I know that. My point was that it's a bit surprising that the matrix for exactness for $j=0,1,\dots,n-1$ is even nonsingular. Somehow "if the nodes are right then correct weights for degree $0,1,\dots,n-1$ implies the weights are also correct for degree up to $2n-1$"? That's a bit weird.

Comment: Then again I guess it is basically a Vandermonde matrix and we know those are nonsingular.

Comment: @Ian One can find $w_i$ this way for 'any' choice of $\theta_i$; by adding that the $\theta_i$ are chosen in a special way, one can add $n$ more places of accuracy.